# pass an argument in on_data function in class StdOutListener in tweepy

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy
import csv
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    #This function gets called every time a new tweet is received on the stream
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(the_argument)
        Client = MongoClient()
        db = Client["Twitter"]
        collection = db[the_argument]
        j=json.loads(data)
        text=j["text"] #The text of the tweet
        collection.insert({'tweet':text})

    def on_error(self, status):
        print("ERROR")
        print(status)

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#'+'hashtag'], encoding='utf8')
```

In the above code, in the `class StdOutListener`, I want to pass argument `the_argument` in `collection = db[the_argument]` in the function `on_data`. How do I pass this argument? I tried different ways of passing through `def on_data(self, data,the_argument)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `on_data` is called by Tweepy in response to a new tweet - not from your own code. Where do you want the value of `the_argument` to come from?

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Sad no one answered you!